# Send post request to spring rest api

Tags: java, spring, rest, intellij-idea

I'm using intelliJIDEA, Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/authors", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public AuthorDTO addNewAuthor(@RequestBody AuthorDTO authorDTO) {
    return authorService.add(authorDTO);
}
```

(`authorService.add` returns an `AuthorDTO` type.)

AuthorDTD.java:

```
public class AuthorDTO {

public AuthorDTO() {
}

public AuthorDTO(Author author) {
    this.id = author.getId();
    this.first_name = author.getFirstName();
    this.last_name = author.getLastName();
}

public AuthorDTO(Long id, String first_name, String last_name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

private Long id;
private String first_name;
private String last_name;
//getter/setters
 }
```

And here is my rest test window:

[image]

But when i send the `POST` request, nothing happens!

json sent: `{"id":"12"}, {"first_name":"aaaa"}, { "last_name": "gggg"}`

Outputs:

response windows: `<Response body is empty>`

Run log:

```
2016-01-13 09:40:18.206  INFO 3892 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-01-13 09:40:18.206  INFO 3892 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-01-13 09:40:18.338  INFO 3892 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 132 ms
```

Comment: What's the type of return in service: authorService.add(authorDTO)???

Comment: @m.aibin It returns an `AuthorDTO` type.

Comment: do you have @Controller above the name of the class and context-component scan in xml file?

Comment: @m.aibin Yes i have.

Comment: ok, you need to provide more config, as I can ask you question after question. Do you have some JSON mapper? For example Jackson JSON Mapper? Did you try to return something different as a response, starting simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the format of JSON, it should be,

```
{"id":12, "first_name":"aaaa",  "last_name": "gggg"}
```

Make sure `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json`